# My Get IP Address C Function is not outputting correct value

Tags: c, networking

Here's My function for getting and outputting the IP address of the wireless en1.

```
char* getIPAddress(char* src)
{

    struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;
    int family;

    if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1) {
        perror("getifaddrs");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
        if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL)
            continue;
        family = ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family;
        if (0 == strcmp(ifa->ifa_name,"en1" ) && (family == AF_INET)) { // v4
            // en1

            inet_ntop(ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family,&((struct sockaddr_in*)ifa)->sin_addr,src,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        }
    }

    freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
    return src;
}
```

I would expect something 129.10.10.50 or something like that but right now it's outputting blank.

Comment: If the connection is inactive for a while, this can happen.  Sending a dummy packet usually fixes that problem.  I'm not sure if the "en1" string is supposed to be "en0" ... thats what I have seen before, unless you have multiple adapters. ... on linux you can use /proc/net/arp

Comment: Have you checked whether your `if` statement with the `inet_ntop()` call in it ever actually evaluates to true and executes?

Answer (score 2):

**This is incorrect:**

```
inet_ntop(
    ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family,
    &((struct sockaddr_in*)ifa)->sin_addr, // <--- casting wrong variable
    src,
    sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)
);
```

You are casting `struct ifaddrs` to `struct sockaddr_in` instead of it's member:

```
struct ifaddrs {
   struct ifaddrs  *ifa_next;    /* Next item in list */
   char            *ifa_name;    /* Name of interface */
   unsigned int     ifa_flags;   /* Flags from SIOCGIFFLAGS */

   struct sockaddr *ifa_addr;    /* Address of interface */  // <--- this one

   struct sockaddr *ifa_netmask; /* Netmask of interface */
   union {
       struct sockaddr *ifu_broadaddr;
                        /* Broadcast address of interface */
       struct sockaddr *ifu_dstaddr;
                        /* Point-to-point destination address */
   } ifa_ifu;
#define              ifa_broadaddr ifa_ifu.ifu_broadaddr
#define              ifa_dstaddr   ifa_ifu.ifu_dstaddr
   void            *ifa_data;    /* Address-specific data */
};
```

**This will fix it:**

```
inet_ntop(
    ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family,
    &((struct sockaddr_in*)ifa->ifa_addr)->sin_addr, // ifa_addr member instead
    src,
    sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)
);
```

You can also break out of the loop too.

Comment: I am getting No source available for "memmove$VARIANT$sse3x() at 0x7fff86e75ee2" when trying to single step the inet_ntop function.

Comment: View and run the test code at coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd2889fc9d4bc07f

Comment: can u use eclipse C/C++? I am using that with MacOSx GCC toolchain under eclipse.  It's not working.